# Using an extension method on a navigation property of an IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, extension-methods

In LINQ to Entities, is it possible to have an extension method that can be used on a navigation property of an entity in an IQueryable?

For example, if I have an Manufacturer entity with navigational property Products, can I do the following:

```
// ManufacturersQuery is an IQueryable<Manufacturer>
from m in ManufacturersQuery
let p = m.Products.ReturnableProducts()
where ...
select ...

// Extension method - This throws the error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ReturnableProducts and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
public static IEnumerable<Product> ReturnableProducts(this IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    return products.Where(p => p.IsReturnable);
}
```

I think this might be possible if the navigational property m.Products returned an IQueryable instead of an ICollection, but I don't know if that can be changed.

Can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: needs to be IQueryable if you want it to be part of the query, otherwise you could to this but only after you call ToList()